How can Nakayama's Lemma be used to extend surjectivity over a point to surjectivity over an open subset?
Let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of schemes and $\mathscr{F}$ a coherent $\mathscr{O}_X$-module. Given a point $y\in Y$, we have the following diagram.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_y @>{i}>> X\\
@VV{g}V @VV{f}V \\
\operatorname{Spec} k(y) @>{j}>> Y
\end{CD}$$
It seems that if $\mathscr{F}_y:=i^*\mathscr{F}=0$, then by Nakayama's Lemma, there exists an affine open set $U\subset Y$ such that $\mathscr{F}|_{f^{-1}(U)}=0$?
For any $x\in X_y$, we have $(i^{*}\mathscr{F})_{x}=\mathscr{F}_x\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}\mathscr{O}_{X_y,x}=\mathscr{F}_x\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}}k(y)$. But $\mathscr{F}_x$ may not be a finitely generated $\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}$-module, so I can't use Nakayama's Lemma.
Or more specifically, to check that $f^*f_*\mathscr{L}\rightarrow \mathscr{L}$ is surjective, why is it enough to check this on any fiber $X_y$? This question arises in the proof that ampleness is an open condition in families(See [Kollár-Mori, Proposition 1.41]) and [Hartshorne, Proposition V.2.2].(Please read the image in the hyperlink.)

Hi, a few tips: $\operatorname{Spec} k(y)$ for $\operatorname{Spec} k(y)$ produces better spacing than $\mathrm{Spec} k(y)$ $\mathrm{Spec} k(y)$; next, images of text are neither searchable nor accessible, and the images you've linked are rather large. Please consider placing the relevant portions inside your post, typeset with MathJax.

This is related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1263724/571974

I'll answer the underlying question. Nakayama's lemma guarantees that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasicoherent sheaf of finite type over a scheme $X$, then $\mathcal{F}=0$ iff $\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k(x)=0$ for all $x$. Letting $i_x:\operatorname{Spec} k(x)\to X$ be the natural inclusion, we can rewrite $\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k(x)$ as $i_x^*\mathcal{F}$, so $\mathcal{F}=0$ iff $i_x^*\mathcal{F}=0$ for all $x\in X$. But if we have a map $f:X\to Y$ and we let $y=f(x)$, then $i_x:\operatorname{Spec} k(x)\to X$ factors as $$\operatorname{Spec} k(x)\stackrel{j_x}{\to} X_y \stackrel{i_{X_y}}{\to} X,$$ and clearly if $i_{X_y}^*\mathcal{F}=0$ for all $y\in Y$, then we get $i_x^*\mathcal{F}=j_x^*i_{X_y}^*\mathcal{F}=0$ for all $x$. So it suffices to prove that $i_{X_y}^*\mathcal{F}=0$ for all $y$ in order to show that $\mathcal{F}=0$.
Your question about an affine open neighborhood also has an affirmative answer. If $i_{X_y}^*\mathcal{F}=0$, then we have that $i_x^*\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k(x)=0$ for all $x\in X_y$, hence $\mathcal{F}_x=0$ for all $x\in X_y$, and so the support of $\mathcal{F}$ is contained in a closed subset $S\subset X$ which does not intersect $X_y$. As a proper morphism is closed, $f(S)\subset Y$ is a closed subset avoiding $y$, hence an affine open neighborhood of $y$ contained in $Y\setminus f(S)$ can be taken to play the role of $U$.

(NB, if you are working over a variety or any other situation where the support of a sheaf of finite type is closed and closed points are dense in every nonempty closed subset, you can do a little better than this - it suffices to check these conditions in the first paragraph over closed points in that case. For instance, this is useful in Hartshorne when he occasionally makes a reduction to only looking at closed points without necessarily saying so much.)
